# how to convert array to observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

As shown in the following code, I would like to use RxAndroid. but I am facing two issues:

1- I want to convert the Array to observable, but the method .fromArray is not recognised

2- Why in the interface of Observer i dont have onSubscribe(Disposable d) implemented?

please let me know hopw to fix these two issues.

**build gradle**

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'
```

**code**:

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

    //fromArray is not defined
  private Observable<String> getAnimalsObservable() {
    return Observable.fromArray(
            "Ant", "Ape",
            "Bat", "Bee", "Bear", "Butterfly",
            "Cat", "Crab", "Cod",
            "Dog", "Dove",
            "Fox", "Frog");
}

//why in the following interface, i dont have onSubscribe(Disposable d)
private Observer<String> getAnimalsObserver() {
    return new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Name: " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "All items are emitted!");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you intend to use RxJava 1 or 2. You are mixing up the two in your last 2 questions.

Comment: @akarnokd please hae alook at the question again, i updated it. the gradle and the imports are included

Comment: You are using RxJava 1 where the operator is named [`from`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#from-T:A-). [`onSubscribe(Disposable)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observer.html#onSubscribe-io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable-) was introduced in RxJava 2 because of a complete rewrite and rearchitecting of the components. Please make sure you read the javadocs and look at what your IDE's code completion suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better upgrade your rxjava, actually you're using rxjava1.

check [latest version](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Then, fromArray should work and you will deal with [DisposableObserver](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableObserver.html) interface or [Observer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observer.html) interface(rxjava >= 2.16).

Note that onSubscribe(Disposable d) is defined inside Observer interface.

hope i will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
private Observable<String> getAnimalsObservable() {
    return Observable.from(Arrays.asList(
        new String[] {
            "Ant", "Ape",
            "Bat", "Bee", "Bear", "Butterfly",
            "Cat", "Crab", "Cod",
            "Dog", "Dove",
            "Fox", "Frog"}
    ));
}
```

you can subscribe like this

```
getAnimalsObservable().subscribe(i -> {
    // Do some thing with 'i', it's a list of String.
});
```

or you can do like this as well

```
Observable.from(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", }))
.subscribe(i -> {
    // Do some thing with 'i', it's a list.
});
```

Comment: would yu please answer the 2nd question as well

Comment: would you please explain, why the return value from getAnimalsObservable() is not Observable<String>[]. 
 Also, still i dont know why i cant use onSubscribe(disposable d)

Answer (score 0):

You are using RxJava 1. I don't remember it clearly, but why not RxJava 2?
On RxJava github:

> The 1.x version is end-of-life as of March 31, 2018. No further development, support, maintenance, PRs and updates will happen. The Javadoc of the very last version, 1.3.8, will remain accessible.

Maybe 2nd version will help to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

use **fromIterable**

example:

```
val arraylist: ArrayList<CustomObject>
Observable.fromIterable(arraylist)
```